# How to fetch and display data from documents in subcollection in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display data from firestore in the simplest way because I'm a beginner in react. Here is the tree of my data of firestore.

collection-[ documentsList [ subcolletcion [ documentsList [ data

Comment: Could you show your code where you fetch data and render data? What issues you are facing there? Which error you have ?

Comment: It's a big tree of my database and I only know the basic of react and the way i fetched the documents from my parent collection is really dumbest way in i think, but anyways i haven't written the code to fetch the data, i want to know how can i fetch data, look at the tree of my database and I successfully displayed the documents of my parent Collection in the table now i want to go to the data in documents in subcollection in documents(that i successfully fetched). Ps : sorry if it's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch data you can do it like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     const getData = async () => {         
       const result = await axios('https://route_to_backend.com/bla-bla'); 
       setData(result.data);
     }
     getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data && data.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <div>{item.title}</div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you provide some example of objects that you receive from server I can write code how you can render it.

Comment: Bro my data looks like this:- [collection - documents - subcollection - documents - data] and i want all the data in my table and from data i want 3 things, ( ITEM ID, ITEM DATE, ITEM STATUS) in table and a button which will take me to a printable page where i want to print all the data from my that documents